# change the player in swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I 'm working in a game and i face a problem I setUp two button when i click the first button t's spawn the first player and when i click the second button it's remove the first player and spawn the second one and every thing it's good but the problem is when i click in the first button it's shud spawn me one node only.

how I can make it spawn one node only then when i ever click not spawn tel i click the other button and the same thing for the second button this is my code help Please..

```
// Set button One

    ButtoneOne = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.size.width / 25, height: frame.size.height / 20))
    ButtoneOne.center = CGPoint(x: view.frame.size.width / 6.5, y: view.frame.size.height / 2)
    ButtoneOne.setImage(ButtonTextureOne, forState: .Normal)
    ButtoneOne.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Play.PlayesrOne), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.view?.addSubview(ButtoneOne)

func PlayesrOne() {

    Player.removeFromParent()
    PlayerTwo.removeFromParent()

    PlayerOne = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "PlayerOne")
    PlayerOne.size = CGSize(width: 150, height: 200)
    PlayerOne.position = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width / 2, y: frame.size.height / 2)
    PlayerOne.zPosition = -1
    self.addChild(PlayerOne)


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that in iOS (and not only in iOS) is a bad attitude give uppercase to your properties.

I don't want to re-factor all your code, I'll try to maintain your structure and methods as possible:

```
buttoneOne = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.size.width / 25, height: frame.size.height / 20))
buttoneOne.center = CGPoint(x: view.frame.size.width / 6.5, y: view.frame.size.height / 2)
buttoneOne.setImage(ButtonTextureOne, forState: .Normal)
buttoneOne.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Play.PlayesrOne), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
self.view?.addSubview(buttoneOne)

func makePlayerOne() {
     if (self.childNodeWithName("playerOne") == nil) {
        playerOne = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "PlayerOne")
        playerOne.size = CGSize(width: 150, height: 200)
        playerOne.position = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width / 2, y: frame.size.height / 2)
        playerOne.zPosition = -1
        playerOne.name = "playerOne"
        self.addChild(playerOne)
     }
}

func PlayesrOne() {
   player.removeFromParent()
   playerOne.removeFromParent()
   playerTwo.removeFromParent()
   makePlayerOne()
}
```

You could make the same thing for player2 spawn..